# Shell script argument present or not

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script, where sometimes user gives the required arg sometimes they forget. So I needed someway in which if the user has already provided the particular argument then the user should not be prompted for that particular arg. Can anyone help?

Example script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $GAME =="" ]
then
    echo Enter path to GAME:
    read GAME
else
    echo $GAME
fi
```

Example O/P 1:

> $ ./sd.sh -GAME asdasd
>   Enter path to GAME:
>   ?asd

Example O/P 2:

> $ ./sd.sh
>   Enter path to GAME:
>   asd

Comment: AFAIK shell scripts don't understand named args without some extra work to parse them.   When you're checking for $GAME, you're actually checking the environment, not your args.

Comment: @cHao: so suppose I want to check for the 3rd arg if its present or not that has a specific name for example: `run.sh -name Abhishek -game COD -type Action` where if the user sometime forgets `type` then he/she should be prompted else if he already provides it as arg then he/she should not be prompted

Comment: The third arg (`$3`) would be "-game".  The arg names don't mean anything unless you pass the args to a getopt-style routine.  If you're going to check by arg number, you may as well get rid of the switches -- they're not doing anything codewise, and they misimply that the order of the args doesn't matter.

Comment: @cHao: I am using the switches because, they are for a java argument that is getting run inside this script, so I will need it. Please suggest some other way. Thanks

Comment: See my answer.  There's a `getopts` command specifically made to handle named args.  (There's a `getopt` as well, but it has some quirks -- for one thing, it doesn't do very well in general with args that have spaces.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version of shell script without using getopts that solves the problem. The problem that i am facing with getopts is to give named arguments as -GAME instead only -g works i.e., single character.

Note: Here -user and -pass args are for java so i don't need sh script to ask it, as java does the job if they are not already provided.

```
#!/bin/sh
game=0
if [ $# -ge 1 ];then
 if [ ${6} = "-GAME" ];then
  game=1
 fi
 if [ $game -ne 1 ];then
  echo "Enter path to GAME location"
  read GAME
 else
  GAME=${7}
 fi
 echo "Game:" $1 ", Game location: " $GAME
else
 echo "usage: ./run.sh gamename"
 echo "usage: ./run.sh gamename [-user] [username] [-pass] [password] [-GAME] [path]"
fi
```

Output 1:

> ./run.sh COD4 -user abhishek -pass hereiam -GAME /home/games 
>   Game: COD4, Game location: /home/games

Output 2:

> ./run.sh COD4
>   ./run.sh: line 4: [: =: unary operator expected
>   Enter path to GAME location
>   /home/mygames
>   Game: COD4, Game location: /home/mygames

Thanks everyone for their efforts :)

Comment: only hitch in this is in the 2nd output where i get `./run.sh: line 4: [: =: unary operator expected` else it works perfectly

Comment: Put a space before the closing bracket.

Answer (score 8):

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 directory"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: What is -z here, because if i use -GAME i get `./sd.sh: test: argument expected`

Comment: @Abhishek: it checks if the length of the first argument is zero.

Comment: This argument parsing error of `test(1)` is reason for the `[ x"$1" = x ]` idiom which prevents "$1" from being interpreted as an option to test.

Comment: It might also be a lack of whitespace. The brackets must be surrounded by whitespace, so you cannot write: `if [-z "$1"]`. This is because `[` is an ordinary shell command which checks that its last argument is `]`. It's not some special syntax built into the shell.

Answer (score 5):

you can check for first argument using `$#`

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
    read -p "Enter game" GAME
else
    GAME="$1"
fi
```

`$#` means number of arguments. This scripts checks whether number of arguments is 1. If you want to check fifth argument, then use `$5`. If you really want something more reliable, you can choose to use `getopts`. Or the GNU [getopt](http://software.frodo.looijaard.name/getopt/docs/getopt-parse.bash) which supports long options

Comment: What way i can refer to the 5th argument, as $# refers to 1st arg

Comment: @Abhishek $# indicates number of arguments. $1 refers to value of specific argumrent, in this case the 1st one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use named args, check out [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html).  It's made for extracting args by name.  That link also has examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
game=""
usage="usage: $0 -g game"
while getopts ":hg:" option; do
  case "$option" in
    h) echo "$usage"
       exit
       ;;
    g) game="$OPTARG"
       ;;
    ?) echo "illegal option: $OPTARG" >&2
       echo "$usage" >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done
[ -z "$game" ] && read -p "enter game: " game
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the info, I managed to make 1 without using OPTGET